# Error: Expected a Type Specifier. C++ Inheritence

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, compiler-errors, identifier

I've been working on creating Shape class files for my class, and up until about 15 additional lines of code, everything was going well. I'm getting one of the standard "Expected type specifier" when I create a 'Rectangle' object. Creating objects of the other two classes (Triangle and Circle) work perfectly. I noticed it bugged out as soon as I added the second vector (shapesTest2), so maybe it has something to do with that?

Specifically, the lines in question are:

```
shapes.push_back(new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4, Blue));
shapesTest2.push_back(new Rectangle(11, 22, 33, 44, Black));
```

The error list says:

```
    IntelliSense: expected a type specifier     29
    IntelliSense: expected a type specifier     30
Error 1 error C2661: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back' : no overloaded function takes 5 arguments   31
Error 2 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')' 31
Error 3 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Rectangle' 31
```

Anyways, here's the code in the main.cpp file.:

```
// main.cpp - Shape class test program
// Written by _______
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Circle.h"
#include "Triangle.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"


using namespace std;

void main()
{
    // Container of Shapes
    vector<Shape*> shapes;
    vector<Shape*> shapesTest2; // Used for second test case of Move and Scale.

    // Must allocate my object on heap now

    Circle *myCircle = new Circle(10, 10, 100, Red);
    shapes.push_back(myCircle);

    // Create new, unnamed stack-allocated instance of a Circles and push_back() to vector
    shapesTest2.push_back(new Circle(20, 20, 20, Red));

    // Populate the Container with 2 Rectangles

    shapes.push_back(new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4, Blue));
    shapesTest2.push_back(new Rectangle(11, 22, 33, 44, Black));

    // Populate the Container with 2 Triangles

    shapes.push_back(new Triangle(3, 4, 5, 7, 15, 4, Black));
    shapesTest2.push_back(new Triangle(6, 7, 9, 8, 43, 15, Green));

// There's more to the file, but this is the only time this pops up, and the rest is
// just messing around with the vector<Shape*>. I figured I'd try and save time and
// space by only posting what's needed, but if you think that the error is caused by
// code below, ask me and I'll upload the rest of this main.cpp file

}
```

And for reference, here's my Rectangle.h file:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "Shape.h"

using namespace std;

// Enum Colors = {Red, Blue, Green, Black, White}; is located in "Shapes.h"

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Colors color) : Shape(x, y, color)
{
    Width = width;
    Height = height;
}

virtual void Scale(float scaleFactor)
{
    Width = int(Width*scaleFactor);
    Height = int(Height*scaleFactor);
}

virtual void Draw() const // const b/c it doesn't alter Radius, X, Y, nor Color
{
    cout << "Rectangle of width " << Width << " and height " << Height << " with the top left corner at (" << X << ", " << Y << ") and color " << GetColor() << ".\n" << endl;
}

private:
int Width;
int Height;
};
```

Thanks for all the help guys, I've tried reading through all the other questions and it looked like people had just forgotten the '#include "*_*"' part of it.

Comment: For future reference: please post the full error. Many [tag:c++] regulars can read between the lines of an error and figure something important out.

Comment: What do you mean by post the full error?

Comment: There should be more details than just "Expected a Type Specifier". Often errors cover multiple lines and have line/column numbers. Are you sure the error doesn't say "Expected type-specifier before <something>"?

Comment: Your rectangle class doesn't include color.h file. How does the compiler frind `Colors` when it compiles rectangle.obj file? Is `Colors` included inside the `Circle` class or its it scoped outside that class?

Comment: It's part of the "Shape.h" parent class, sorry for the confusion. We were writing this in class with our professor and it looks like we both forgot to delete that comment. Will fix ^.^

Also copied the error list into here, hopefully it makes more sense.

When I'm typing into VS2012, the autocomplete recognizes that Rectangle class exists, however it looks like it doesn't see the constructor.

Comment: If you break the new rectangles out to their own lines and then pass in those pointers (like you did with the first `Circle`), what error do you get?

Comment: Saying "when I call on 'Rectangle'. " isn't detailed enough for me. Doesn't the error point you to a specific line of code? Also, you shouldn't have to guess that the rest of the file doesn't matter. Comment out the rest of the file and test again. (Most IDEs have keyboard shortcuts that will toggle line commenting for all selected lines).  One additional editorial comment, it's generally a **very bad** idea to put a using statement (in your case `using namespace std;`) in an include file. Any code that uses your .h brings all of std into scope.

Comment: At this point in the dialog, it looks like the compiler doesn't know how to turn a new Rectangle() into Shape* to be placed into the vector.

Comment: @Tod

At the top, I pointed out the two lines in error are:

    `shapes.push_back(new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4, Blue));`
    `shapesTest2.push_back(new Rectangle(11, 22, 33, 44, Black));`

As for the rest of the file, it isn't commented out in my actual IDE, I just didn't want to make this question super long, and in doing so, make it even harder to keep things organized and concise. 

Would you like me to post the rest of the main.cpp code? It'll add another 70 lines or so.

Comment: @StarPilot I just tried 'Rectangle *myRectangle = new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4, Red);'

I received these errors _just for that one line_:

    `[Error 1: error C2065: 'myRectangle' : undeclared identifier]`
    `[Error 2: error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Rectangle']`
    `[3 IntelliSense: identifier "myRectangle" is undefined]`
    `[4 IntelliSense: expected a type specifier]`

Comment: I suspect that `Rectangle` is already defined somewhere in `windows.h`. Rename your Rectangle class to "ThisRectangle" or something else like that, and try it again.

Comment: ^Turns out it was the Windows.h Library inclusion that caused the issue. Thanks a lot for the help everyone, I appreciate the super quick responses and would have never guessed there was a name conflict.

Comment: A quick test verifies that `Rectangle` is defined by `windows.h`. Rename your `Rectangle` class or stop using `windows.h`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of the error is some sort of name conflict caused by the inclusion of `windows.h`. Remove the line

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

and everything compiles.

**Edit:** 
To avoid such a conflict you can place your classes in a namespace. In the header write something like:

namespace Foo {
     class Rectangle { ... };
   }

Comment: There's a name conflict? That's a bummer, I wanted to use the Sleep Function from that library.

Thanks for the help, that works perfectly. Since I don't have 15 rep, someone upvote this for me?

Comment: You can wrap all your code in a namespace (a good practice anyway) or you could rename Rectangle to something else (MyRectangle?).

Comment: I changed it to Rectangles.h, and it seems to have worked ^.^.

What do you mean by wrapping all my code in a namespace, as in Rectangles::Rectangles(1, 2, 3, 4, Blue);? --EDIT: looks like Thomas edited his answer ^.^, thanks again

Comment: A namespace is something to help prevent name clashes. When your  symbols are in the global namespace, it is much more likely to have a name conflict. Just like the symbols from the standard library are in the std namespace, you can place your files in their own namespace.